# Vuejs: vue-color is not changing picker location if linked v-model value is changed

Tags: vue.js, color-picker

I am using Sketch option of [vue-color](https://github.com/xiaokaike/vue-color) for color picking. It uses `v-model` to communicate color change as follows:

```
<sketch-picker v-model="colors" />
```

where `colors` is a data initialised as below:

```
colors: {hex: "#c0392b", a: 1}
```

When page is loaded color-picker is at expected position i.e. (hex: #c0392b). On changing picker position, `colors` value changed as expected.

Issue comes when I change `colors` value in a method like below:

```
this.colors.hex = "#ff00ff";
this.colors.a = 0.5;
```

In this case even though data `colors` value is changed(this is confirmed), color-picker is still pointing at old location i.e. #c0392b.

I don't think this is an expected behavior and possibly a bug. What should be way-around this issue?

Comment: Could you show more codes on how to declare the `data property=colors`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting changes in objects is a bit nuanced in Vue/JavaScript. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats and the deep option of watch https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch

You may simply need to use

```
this.colors = Object.assign({}, this.colors, { a: 0.5, hex: "#ff00ff" })
```

Comment: Great answer! I forgot about this. But this hasn't solved the issue completely. Please look at question edit and If you can think of any reason it is happening

Comment: This is working, other issue I was having was due to another reason.